# How to allow infinite scrolling in the both directions with md-virtual-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, infinite-scroll, angularjs-material

I've implemented an [infinite horizontal scroll using md-virtual-repeat](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat#infinite-scroll). It fetches 25 records each time when needed when I scroll to the right.

```
<md-virtual-repeat-container flex md-orient-horizontal>
  <div md-virtual-repeat="item in $ctrl.infiniteItems" md-on-demand>
    {{ item.date }}
  </div>
</md-virtual-repeat-container>
```

Essentially it's a horizontal list of dates (with other information) that you can scroll in. You scroll to the future dates. Works fine.

Now, I want to also scroll to the left where the dates of the past are.

I'm looking for a way to start in the middle (where today's date is). I've tried setting `md-top-index` by a value on the controller, but it gets reset to a low number after the first page is fetched from the server.

```
<md-virtual-repeat-container flex md-orient-horizontal md-top-index="$ctrl.topIndex">
  <div md-virtual-repeat="item in $ctrl.infiniteItems" md-on-demand>
    {{ item.date }}
  </div>
</md-virtual-repeat-container>
```

How can I configure `md-virtual-repeat-container` and `md-virtual-repeat` to allow scrolling to the left as well as to the right?

*Update: Here's a sandbox with Codepen of the situation that I'd like to accomodate with a button to scroll leftwards. https://codepen.io/christiaanwesterbeek/pen/pLRQgg*

*Update2: Setting an `md-top-index` to some positive integer allows scrolling in both directions. But the [example](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat#scroll-to) given at the angular material site with `md-top-index` is not about infinite scrolling. The solution to my question is where `md-top-index` meets infinite scrolling.*

Answer (score 0):

well .. to answer you question :

you can allow scrolling in the reverse direction of md-virtual-repeat by changing the `body` tag of your `html` document to `<body dir="rtl">`

a quick rundown :

i looked for this everywhere but i couldn't find anything and i assume you did too, so i downloaded `angular-material.js` from [angular cdn](https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.8/angular-material.js)  locally to see how they handle this, here's a snippet :

```
VirtualRepeatContainerController.prototype.handleScroll_ = function() {
  var ltr = document.dir != 'rtl' && document.body.dir != 'rtl';
  if(!ltr && !this.maxSize) {
    this.scroller.scrollLeft = this.scrollSize;
    this.maxSize = this.scroller.scrollLeft;
  }
  var offset = this.isHorizontal() ?
      (ltr?this.scroller.scrollLeft : this.maxSize - this.scroller.scrollLeft)
      : this.scroller.scrollTop;

  if (offset === this.scrollOffset || offset > this.scrollSize - this.size) return;

  var itemSize = this.repeater.getItemSize();
  if (!itemSize) return;

  var numItems = Math.max(0, Math.floor(offset / itemSize) - NUM_EXTRA);

  var transform = (this.isHorizontal() ? 'translateX(' : 'translateY(') +
      (!this.isHorizontal() || ltr ? (numItems * itemSize) : - (numItems * itemSize))  + 'px)';

  this.scrollOffset = offset;
  this.offsetter.style.webkitTransform = transform;
  this.offsetter.style.transform = transform;

  if (this.bindTopIndex) {
    var topIndex = Math.floor(offset / itemSize);
    if (topIndex !== this.topIndex && topIndex < this.repeater.getItemCount()) {
      this.topIndex = topIndex;
      this.bindTopIndex.assign(this.$scope, topIndex);
      if (!this.$rootScope.$$phase) this.$scope.$digest();
    }
  }

  this.repeater.containerUpdated();
};
```

this is how i found that they rely on the body's direction to direct the infinit scrolling, so if you don't want to change the direction of your `html` document, you'll have to download it, edit this part and use it instead of the `cdn` , however .. it won't work as expected;

in normal situation, scrolling from left to right will increment the `this.scrollLeft` variable and as you can see in the snippet it's used everywhere, it will increment the `offset` and the `translateX()` and everything will fall into the right place,

but if you're scrolling from right to the left, the `handleScroll_` function will set the `this.scrollOfsset` to the width of the view and as you scroll to left, `this.scrollLeft` will decrease instead of increasing and once you reach the end of your first 25 everything will break apart,

i tried `console.log` of all the variables inside and compared the `rtl` with the `ltr` to see when and where things break, i tried to play around with the values and operations but no success, feel free to do the same and experiment maybe i missed something ( but hey, the question is only about changing the direction right ? :P )

i would recommend you to go for something else ( like the ones in the comments above )

i hope this helps or at least gives you an idea, good luck.

**EDIT :**

since this depends on the `body`'s direction, you can either scroll left or right, not both, even if you set `md-top-index` and start in the middle ( with`dir="ltr"` ) , you'll only have infinit scrolling on one side ( to the right ) if you go back, it's just displaying old already loaded data,

you can take a look at `VirtualRepeatController.prototype.virtualRepeatUpdate_` inside the `js` file to see how it adds the new blocks and update indexes and the scroll.

on a side note: people wanted this for reverse vertical scrolling ( for chat apps ) and there are open issues but it's not likely to be added since they moved to angular 2.x and above

bottom line is : if you want scrolling on both sides with only configuration, i'm afraid you can't, and if you absolutely want this you're going to have to modify `angular-material.js` to fit your needs.

Comment: It looks like you assumed that I need *only* scrolling to the left, but I actually need scrolling to both directions. This rtl approach does not allow scrolling in both directions.

Comment: i edited my answer to be more precise, i know you wanted scrolling on both sides, maybe i just didn't express myself very well, but i elaborated on how the scrolling to the left can be difficult,  adding blocks to the start ( the left ) is gonna mess up the indexes and everything else, because with `dir="rtl"` the new blocks are added to the end and it's just a matter of direction and the blocks are not really added to the start

Comment: Setting a `md-top-index` to some positive integer allows scrolling to both directions. But the example given at the angular material site with `md-top-index` is not about infinite scrolling. The solution to my question is where `md-top-index` meets inifite scrolling. I hope I can trigger you to own the solution and earn the bounty :)

Comment: hmm yeah i see what you mean, setting `md-top-index` will jump to that index ( i saw it here https://codepen.io/colinskow/pen/jbVaRj ) and mentioned it the edit, but this will stop when it goes back and reaches the start, i thought the idea is to scroll infinitely in both directions, like when you scroll to the left and you reach `0` will start seeing `-1,-2,-3` ..etc. i found the example in the link but i didn't think about adding `setting up md-top-index` to the answer because it's not infinite scrolling , i was hoping to get the bounty as it will be my first but it's up to you to decide :)

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but your answer is more like a log of your investigation. I will award the bounty to a real solution.

Comment: There are 24 hours left for me to award the bounty. If you can get this to work within that period I will award the bounty to you. After the 24 hours, I can't award it to you anymore... I know there's a solution without modifying `angular-material.js`. There's just some smartness that has to be implemented in the getItemAtIndex, fetchMoreItems_ methods this. Probably 2 arrays are involved. One for going one direction and one for going the opposite direction.